# How to write string with octal value

Tags: bash

In bash, I would like to write the string `"BLA\1"`
so it will be a buffer `42 4C 41 01` but the result is `42 4C 41 5C 31`

To complete, in python if you write `"BLA\1"` in a binary file, the `"\1"` is interpreted as `"1"`

So how can I write the string `"BLA\1"` correctly in bash?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `$''` special quotes:

```
echo -n $'BLA\1' | xxd
00000000: 424c 4101                                BLA.
```

Comment: @Nicosmik: "Thanks" on StackOverflow = Upvote and/or Accept.

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf`, defined by the POSIX standard:

```
printf 'BLA\1'
```

Some `bash`-specific options:

```
# Let echo expand the escape code
echo -ne 'BLA\1'

# Use $'...', as in choroba's answer
echo -n $'BLA\1'
```

Comment: `printf 'BLA\1' | xxd` works fine but `echo -e 'BLA\1'` add a LF chararcter

Comment: I forgot the `-n` option to suppress the newline that `echo` adds. I'm not entirely sure why I included `echo` in this answer, though; `printf` is portable and reliable.